# How can I add role to user for specified time?

Tags: discord, discord.js

How can I add role to user for specified time?
E.g: user get role and after 24h bot remove this role from user.

Comment: When you add a role to a user, save unix timestamp. Add 24 hours to unix timestamp. Save that value (in a json file, database, ...) uniquely identified by the discord.Member (guild + user id). Write a loop that periodically iterates over. When current unixtimestamp exceeds the saved timestamp generate the discord.Member object and remove the role.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// <member> is a placeholder for a GuildMember object. 
// See link below to find the difference between user object and guildmember object.
// You can get a member with guild.fetchMember(), 
// Or with guild.member() if the member is already cached.

<member>.roles.add(role); // GuildMember .add() method (add role to member)

setTimeout(() => { // evaluates expression after x number of miliseconds

<member>.roles.remove(role) // function to evaluate (GuildMember .remove() method)
// do something else maybe

}, 86400000) // 24 hours in ms
```

[GuildMember Info](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-guildmember)

[`guild.FetchMember()` Method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchMember)

[`guild.member()` Method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member)

[GuildMember `.add()` and `.remove()` Method Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add)

[`setTimeout()` Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: Add some context and explanation along with code, that will be complete and help the community.

Comment: @ArunVinoth sorry about that, I'm really new with StackOverflow . I edited my answer, hopefully it's clearer now 